# MathJax SVGs look poor

Tags: javascript, svg, mathjax

SVGs generated by MathJax look much worse than the HTML/CSS output.

```html
<script src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<div>$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$</div>
```

[image]

```html
<script src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG"></script>
<div>$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$</div>
```

[image]

These images are from Chrome 37 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Firefox 32 showed the same.

Is there a way to get SVG output that looks like the first example?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can go for the static `MATHQUILL` that is a much faster way of getting the mathematical equations. However mathquill.js sometimes gets random. HOwever if you will use the static mathquill, you will never face any issues. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

By default "blackness" is set to 10, and makes it looks like a bad photocopy.

Setting it to 0 takes care of most of the problem.

```html
<script src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_SVG"></script>
<script>
   MathJax.Hub.Config({SVG:{blacker:0}});
</script>
<div>$$a^2+b^2=c^2$$</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.